# cannot work out red5 link in linux to input rtmp for player

Tags: streaming, links

I have red5 server working on Centos 6 thanks to answers in this forum but now I am stuck trying to get linking correct for viewing through player with component requiring RTMP link. I created my own player in flash cs6 and i can see the folder of streams on my linux system but can't configure link correctly.

If the path is /usr/local/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/hobbit_vp6.flv
how does this translate as an rtmp link?

Anyway I can view both streaming live and streaming saved video via the red5 testing page but as I said can't seem to work out link to get 
it to play in my player for a webpage.

VideoError: 1000: Unable to make connection to server or to find FLV on server

update: this might be answer looking for :
http://blog.endpoint.com/2012/04/streaming-live-with-red5-media-server.html

Comment: Are you saying that you can't get it to play anywhere except locally?

Comment: cannot get a player embedded in my webpage to play it because rtmp link doesn't work

Comment: it is playing from the remote server

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: http://www.unibia.com/unibianet/freebsd/quick-and-easy-rtmp-flash-streaming-video-red5-freebsd?page=0,4. This thread might help too: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/servers-and-streaming/9574/how-to-stream-live-to-red5/

Comment: This URL shows the publisher: http://localhost:5080/demos/publisher.html

Comment: I found the swf to test it here http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2918563/flvplayback.swf and the link i've been trying to use in my player WORKS in this one- however obviously you must indicate file to be opened- I don't know how to do that in command line link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/usr/local/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams/hobbit_vp6.flv translates to:

rtmp://localhost:1935/oflaDemo/hobbit_vp6.flv

Of course, if your browser is not running on the red5 server, replace 'localhost' with the IP or fqdn.  Also, since this is CentOS, you may have to tweak your Selinux if it is enforcing mode, and allow port 1935 in your iptables rules, if you implemented iptables.

Comment: Sorry I should have closed this issue a while back because got the links correct weeks ago but you have really helped regarding the iptables rules, that is something I haven't got to yet. I'm not sure how to tweak but will get back to that, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. I figured you resolved, but since other responders only gave links, I thought I'd help everyone else with an actual answer. To allow inbound port 1935, 1) type 'iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT' (without the quotes) to /etc/sysconfig/iptables 2) save with 'service iptables save' 3) restart with 'service iptables restart'

Comment: for step 1 above, just type it on command line, do not add the entry to /etc/sysconfig/iptables  -  step #2 will add it for you and the file path I gave is where you can look to see it is saved.